# ajax getJSON loads data correctly but does not log on console

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I try to load json data from another url into my html getJSON seems to work in the chrome Devtools Network i can see the data with status 200. but i don't get the "it works".

here is my code :

```
<div id="demo">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
            $.getJSON( '/data/', function(data) {
                console.log('it works');
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            console.log('error', status, error) }
            );
        </script>
    </div>
```

here is the error in Console:

```
error parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

also I am using python django as backend.

Comment: because it is logging from error. As `jQuery.getJSON()` is shorthand ajax call for getting json values and your backend has some error in producing some valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, it is successfully getting the request fulfilled, but it is not a valid JSON. JSON conversion wasn't possible here. Change your code to:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
  $.get( '/data/', function(data) {
    console.log('it works');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
    console.log('error', status, error)
  });
</script>
```

Here, you won't get the error plus, you can check if the `data` is a valid JSON format, then you can do:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is successfully fulfilled and you are getting response.

```
 $.getJSON( '/data/', function(data) {
      console.log('it works');
 });
```

This will generate error due to your response may contains some non JSON text.